# How do I select specific cells from ALL worksheets without knowing the exact number of worksheets?

Tags: excel, vba, numbers, worksheet

I'm a total beginner. Here's a part of my code:

```
Workbooks("xxx").Worksheets(1).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy

Workbooks("yyy").Worksheets(1).Activate
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Workbooks("xxx").Worksheets(2).Activate
Range("A2").Select
Selection.Copy

Workbooks("yyy").Worksheets(1).Activate
Range("B3").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Each xxx workbook contains an unknown number of worksheets. It can be 3, it can be 50. If I manually copy & paste the code above eg. 50 times, if the number of worksheets is equal to 30 the macro will display an error and stop. How can I automate this? Pls, keep in mind that I'm new at this so keep your answers simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below Code.

```
Dim wbX As Workbook
Dim wbY As Workbook
Set wbX = Application.Workbooks("xxx")
Set wbY = Application.Workbooks("yyy")

For i = 1 To wbX.Sheets.Count
  wbX.Sheets(i).Activate
  Range("A" & i).Select
  Selection.Copy

  wbY.Sheets(1).Activate
  Range("B" & i + 1).Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
Next
```

Comment: Thanks but that's not what I'm after. Workbook yyy is always comprised of  one worksheet. It's workbook xxx that has a random number of worksheets. I probably didn't make that clear.

Comment: Almost works. I know where the problem lies but I don't know how to fix it. Regardless of the worksheet number I want the macro to always copy the same cell eg. copy A1 from worksheet1, copy A1 from worksheet2, copy A1 from worksheet3.... Your code makes it so that the copied cell is dependent on the worksheet number.

Comment: You want to Copy always A1 from each sheet and paste it to B1,B2,B3.... of yyy Workbook Sheet1. Am i right?

Comment: Exactly. OMG I'm an idiot - got it. Range("A" & i).Select needs to be changed to Range("A1"). I learned a lot today. Thank you, you made my day :)

Comment: You are Welcome. Can you please mark it as Answered

Comment: Dude Mark the Question as answered. i am not expecting to say answered by Siva

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Siva. THANK YOU!

```
Dim wbX As Workbook
Dim wbY As Workbook
Set wbX = Application.Workbooks("xxx")
Set wbY = Application.Workbooks("yyy")

For i = 1 To wbX.Sheets.Count
wbX.Sheets(i).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy

wbY.Sheets(1).Activate
Range("B" & i + 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Next
```